# Creating a leader board in Python - code explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x

A user uploaded this leader board code and it worked but has no explanation. Can someone please explain this so I can adapt it to my code.

```
import csv

score=input("whats ya score")
username=input("whats ya name")

with open ("protleader.csv", "a", newline='') as file:
    fields=['score', 'name']
    writer=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writerow({'score' : score, 'name' : username})

with open ("protleader.csv", "r") as file:
    sortlist=[]
    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for i in reader:
        sortlist.append(i)
for i in range(len(sortlist)):
    if i != 0:
        sortlist[i][0]=int(sortlist[i][int(0)])


print("")

print("Unsorted:")
for i in range(len(sortlist)):
    print(sortlist[i])


for i in range(555):
    for i in range(len(sortlist)-1):
        if i != 0:
            if sortlist[i][0] < sortlist[i+1][0]:
                change=sortlist[i]
                sortlist[i]=sortlist[i+1]
                sortlist[i+1]=change


print("")

print("Sorted and cut:")
for i in range(len(sortlist)-1):
    print(sortlist[i])
```

The below code is my adapted one but it shows multiple different leaderboards and I can't change it! Any help would be great!

```
import csv

            score=input("whats ya score")
            username=input("whats ya name")


            with open ("protleader.csv", "a", newline='') as file:
                fields=['score', 'name']
                writer=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
                writer.writerow({'score' : score, 'name' : username})

            with open ("protleader.csv", "r") as file:
                sortlist=[]
                reader=csv.reader(file)
                for i in reader:
                    sortlist.append(i)
                    for i in range(len(sortlist)):
                        if i != 0:
                            sortlist[i][0]=int(sortlist[i][int(0)])


                    print("")

                    for i in range(len(sortlist)):
                        (sortlist[i])


                    for i in range(1000):
                        for i in range(len(sortlist)-1):
                            if i != 0:
                                if sortlist[i][0] < sortlist[i+1][0]:
                                    change=sortlist[i]
                                    sortlist[i]=sortlist[i+1]
                                    sortlist[i+1]=change


                    print("")

                    print("Leaderboard:")
                    for i in range(len(sortlist)-1):
                        print(sortlist[i])


            break
```

I have tried to change it but it results in error messages. I would like for it to just show the one leader board. In the file is peoples scores: [image]

Answer (score 0):

## try this out, it might help

## use try and except in python

---

[please view this image for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFdYA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Code,

```
import csv

score=input("whats ya score : ")
if score.isalpha():
    print("Invalid Score")
else:
    username=input("whats ya name : ")
    if username.isnumeric():
        print( "Invalid Name" )
    else:
        with open ("protleader.csv", "a", newline='') as file:
            fields=['score', 'name']
            writer=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
            writer.writerow({'score' : score, 'name' : username})

        with open ("protleader.csv", "r") as file:
            sortlist=[]
            reader=csv.reader(file)
            for i in reader:
                sortlist.append(i)
        for i in range(len(sortlist)):
            if i != 0:
                sortlist[i][0]=int(sortlist[i][int(0)])


        print("")

        print("Unsorted:")
        for i in range(len(sortlist)):
            print(sortlist[i])


        for i in range(555):
            for i in range(len(sortlist)-1):
                if i != 0:
                    if sortlist[i][0] < sortlist[i+1][0]:
                        change=sortlist[i]
                        sortlist[i]=sortlist[i+1]
                        sortlist[i+1]=change


        print("")

        print("Sorted and cut:")
        for i in range(len(sortlist)-1):
            print(sortlist[i])
```

Comment: I have updated but after I type my name and score it still comes up with an error message: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Jessica'

Comment: Kindly run above code or paste your code to check error.

Comment: I will past my adapted code above but it comes up with multiple leader boards not just one.